# making insertion sort in scheme using loop

Tags: scheme

Recently, I learned the language of skimming for the first time. I try to implement insertion alignment using a scheme. However, at this time, I tried to implement it using only iterations such as map, for-each, and let loops without recursing. But it didn't work out and failed to implement it. When I try to implement the following code, the phrases "macro name used as variable" and "set!" appear, resulting in grammatical errors.

```
(define tlst '())
(define (insertion-sort lst)
  (for-each
   (lambda (x)
     (let loop ((temp-lst (cdr(member i (reverse lst)))))
       (cond
        ((> x (car temp-lst)) set! lst (append (reverse(cdr temp-lst))(append i ((member (car temp-lst) (lst))))) )
        (else (loop (cdr temp-lst)))
        )
       )
     )
   lst
   )
  )
```

The place where I live is not an English-speaking country, so I wrote an article because I could not obtain related knowledge only in my language.

Comment: Your `cond` syntax is wrong, you're missing `()` around the `set!` assignment.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, when I fixed it, I found another error.

Comment: You have an extra set of parentheses around this: `((member (car temp-lst) (lst)))`. You need to learn basic syntax.

Comment: that's "scheming" as in "conniving" or "planning". not "skimming".

Comment: this has way too many errors (e.g., what is `i`?). start with something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

[Example of recursive insertion sort](https://pritesh-shrivastava.github.io/blog/2021/05/30/quick-sort-insertion-sort)
[from Pritesh Shrivastava]:

```
; sorts a list l in increasing order
; List-of-numbers -> List-of-numbers
(define (insertion-sort l)
  (cond
    [(null? l) '() ]
    [else (insert (car l) (insertion-sort (cdr l))) ]))

; We now define the 'insert' function from our wish list, after which our problem is solved.
; Helper function that inserts a number n into a sorted list of numbers l at its correct position 
; Number List-of-numbers -> List-of-numbers
(define (insert n l)
  (cond
    [(null? l) (cons n '()) ]
    [else (if (<= n (first l))
              (cons n l)
              (cons (car l) (insert n (cdr l)))) ]))

; testing the insert sort function with an example
(insertion-sort '(72 45 43 29 34))
```

The recursive call in `insertion-sort` can be replaced by an "accumulator argument" in a named let:

```
(define (insertion-sort l) ;; List-of-numbers -> List-of-numbers
  ;; produce copy of l sorted in increasing order
  (let build-result ([l l] [result '()])
    (cond
      [(null? l) result ]
      [else (build-result (cdr l) (insert (car l) result)) ])))
```

(The `build-result` call is in tail position, so this is an iterative computation.)

Similarly in `insert` (partial result built by `cons`, so needs `reverse`):

```
(define (insert n l) ;; Number List-of-numbers -> List-of-numbers
  ;; produce result of inserting n into sorted l (may share tail of l)
  (let insert-n ([l l] [result '()])
    (cond
      [(null? l) (append (reverse result) (list n)) ]
      [else (if (<= n (first l))
                (append (reverse result) (list n) l)
                (insert-n (cdr l) (cons (first l) result))) ])))
```